# How to use StreamBuilder inside CustomScrollWidget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, stream-builder

I'm trying to show some data from sqlite and everything is ok but I can't use StreamBuilder inside CustomScrollView it says:

**A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type
RenderPositionedBox.**

Then I wrapped StreamBuilder with SliverPadding (normally SliverPadding was wrapped by StreamBuilder) but this time it says:

**A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type
RenderPositionedBox.**

I tried to use SliverToBoxAdapter and wrapped StreamBuilder with this but didn't solve my problem so How  can I achieve this?

Here is last status of my code:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      floating: false,
      snap: false,
      pinned: false,
      expandedHeight: 0,
      elevation: 3,
      forceElevated: true,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      title: Text(
        'Your Lists',
        style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
            fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 74),
      sliver: StreamBuilder<List<Category>>(
          stream: bloc.getAll().asStream(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Category>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SliverGrid(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index == snapshot.data.length) {
                    return ListAddCard();
                  }
                  return ListCard(
                    category: snapshot.data[index],
                  );
                }, childCount: snapshot.data.length + 1),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.1),
              );
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Use builder as a parent of customscrollview

Comment: Thanks @pskink it worked, but this solution is inefficient right? Because you rerender all CustomScrollView but I want to rerender only slivergrid. Is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: how often your stream emits new values? every second? ten times per second? faster?

Comment: btw, the other order works too: `child: CustomScrollView(
slivers: [
SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text('header')),),
SliverToBoxAdapter(
child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (i) => 'text $i'),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
return Container(
height: 100,
color: Colors.green,
child: Text(snapshot.data ?? 'waiting...', textScaleFactor: 2,),
);
}
),
),
SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(height: 1000, color: Colors.blue, child: Text('footer')),),
],
),`

Comment: @pskink  When you add new category or delete it or rename it. Thanks for other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is that you should wrap your entire CustomScrollView inside the Streambuilder rather than the other way round. I was facing the same issue till I used this strategy.

Comment: Or you could try wrapping your ListAddCard() and ListCard() in a SliverToBoxAdapter because these are probably the widgets causing the error as they may not be Slivers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `SliverPadding` expects a `RenderSliverPadding` but you are giving it a `RenderPositionedBox`. What you could do instead is to remove `SliverPadding` and wrap it in `SliverGrid` instead of in `StreamBuilder`.
Try this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Category>>(
          stream: bloc.getAll().asStream(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Category>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return  SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 74),
      sliver: SliverGrid(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index == snapshot.data.length) {
                    return ListAddCard();
                  }
                  return ListCard(
                    category: snapshot.data[index],
                  );
                }, childCount: snapshot.data.length + 1),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.1),),
              );
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I tried your solution but didn't work, thx though :)

Comment: A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderPositionedBox.